# GlSurfaceView Renderer not being called

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL on Android.  I've written an app where the GlSurfaceView is declared in the layout XML  (fragment...)

```
  <FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/framelay"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <com.nelsondev.myha3ogl.M3View
     android:id="@+id/m3SurfView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
  </FrameLayout>
```

... and in its constructor the renderer is being set:

```
    public M3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        renderer = new M3Renderer(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
   }
```

When the activity receives *onResume/onPause* it is properly calling the GlSurfaceView methods.    **But the renderer is never being started!**  Breakpoints in *onSurfaceCreated()* and other methods in the renderer are never being hit and nothing is rendered.   How do I figure out what's happening here?

Comment: Actually, I just checked and I think my answer to your previous question was wrong, and that actually, start() is called on the GLSurfaceView when it is first laid out (i.e. when you call `setContentView(framelay)` or `setContentView(R.layout.graphics)` with the GLSurfaceView as a child of framelay / in the file graphics.xml) rather than when `setRenderer` is called

Comment: Are you sure that the constructor is being called?

Comment: Can you call `requestRender()` on the GLSurfaceView to see if draws at all?

Comment: Yes the renderer constructor IS being called.

Comment: And you are absolutely certain that your renderer is working and should give an output? What happens if you log a message from the onDrawFrame() method?

Comment: If I put logging messages in onSurfaceCreate, onSurfaceChanged, and onDrawFrame, none of them get hit.   I'll post a new question with detailed source code so you can see a clear example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer comes from your other question :  [Trying to start renderer from GLSurfaceView declared in layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555144/trying-to-start-renderer-from-glsurfaceview-declared-in-layout/8555304#8555304))

You didn't specify your LinearLayout orientation, so it is set to `horizontal` by default. This means your GLSurfaceView is outside of the screen (because you set your button width to `fill_parent`).

Just add the following attribute to your LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```